# Can a ViewBag.Something transport data from view to the controller as well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following case:

```
@model MvcApp.Models.MyAppModel
@{ ViewBag.ActionName = this.Context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]; }
```

using the debugger i checked and i am certain that Viewbag.ActionName recieves its value.
However in the controller ViewBag is always empty. WHY? i am using this between these requests only ( meaning that i always respect this order, from this view i click an actionlink that always takes me to delete. Please enlighten me. Cheers.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    string actionName = ViewBag.ActionName;
```

any details you need just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the view bag is only valid for the duration of a single request. But your talking about two requests: the first one renders the page and the second one processes the *Delete* action. That's why the view bag is initially empty in the controller.

Comment: thank you, you are correct, based on your answer i searched further and you are right.

Comment: i guess model-view-controller is just the concept name not the applied order.

Comment: The MVC name is older than web technologies. It doesn't refer to the order.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of a request is: First the controller, then the View.

So the answer is no, what you do in the view, can not carry over to the action/controller.